# How to use the two_line_list_item in android?

Tags: java, android

I have a `ListView` and the following adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, items);
```

where `items` has the following type: `ArrayList<Item>`

The class items looks like:

```
public class Item {

    String foo1;
    String foo2;

    public String getLine1() {
        return foo1;
    }
    public String getLine2() {
        return foo2;
    }
}
```

but this is not working. Is it not possible to implement is this simple way?

Comment: use a custom listview with a custom adapter

Comment: where do I find a good tutorial for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it not possible to implement is this simple way?

No, because that is not how `ArrayAdapter` works. You are welcome to create your own subclass of `ArrayAdapter`, override `getView()`, and fill in `android.R.id.text1` and `android.R.id.text2` with `getLine1()` and `getLine2()`.